# how to check first row and column of grid view using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview with two columns. I want to check first row and first column should be mandatory. If first column is blank it should not allow to save and it should display message as

> one row should be compulsary.

How to check this?

My save button click coding is as below

```
Dim row As GridViewRow 
For Each row In GridView1.Rows 
If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then 
    Dim t1 As String = CType(row.FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox).Text 
    Dim dd As String = CType(row.FindControl("DropDownList3"), DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text 
    If Trim(t1) = "" Or (Trim(dd)= "" then 
        label6.Text = "HospNo,Date,SurgeryCode/Method are Mandatory" 
    End If
```

but this checks all grid columns, i want to check only first row and column.

Comment: You should show us your `GridView` and [what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: my save button click coding is as below
Dim row As GridViewRow
For Each row In GridView1.Rows
If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
Dim t1 As String = CType(row.FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox).Text
dim dd As String = CType(row.FindControl("DropDownList3"), DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text
if Trim(t1) = "" Or (Trim(dd)="" then
label6.Text = "HospNo,Date,SurgeryCode/Method are Mandatory"
end if  but this checks for all grid columns i want to check only first row and column

Comment: There's an edit button (done already for you).

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each row In GridView1.Rows 
 If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then 
 Dim t1 As String = CType(row.FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox).Text 
 Dim dd As String = CType(row.FindControl("DropDownList3"),DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text 
If Trim(t1) = "" Or (Trim(dd)= "" then 
    label6.Text = "HospNo,Date,SurgeryCode/Method are Mandatory" 
End If
 Exit For
 End For
```

Comment: can u give complete idea i didnt get thanks for immediate response

Comment: in my grid i am showing 2 rows in this i want to check first row and first column and then save Pls help me dis is vry arjent

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GridView1.Rows(0)` to get the first row:

```
Dim firstRow = GridView1.Rows(0)
Dim TextBox2 = DirectCast(firstRow.FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox)
Dim DropDownList3 = DirectCast(firstRow.FindControl("DropDownList3"), DropDownList)
If TextBox2.Text.Trim.Length = 0 OrElse DropDownList3.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
    label6.Text = "HospNo,Date,SurgeryCode/Method are Mandatory"
End If
```

But this is not the approach you should use in ASP.NET. Instead use [`RequiredFieldValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which can ven validate on client-side.

For example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Grid1_SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" Width="300">
        <RowStyle  CssClass="GridViewRowStyle" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridViewAlternatingRowStyle" />
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Aqua" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column 1" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtColumn1" Text='<%# Bind("Column1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"
                        EnableClientScript="true"
                        ControlToValidate="TxtColumn1"
                        Display="Static"
                        ErrorMessage="HospNo,Date,SurgeryCode/Method are Mandatory" 
                        runat="server"/> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: i tried but for line Dim firstRow = GridView1.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow).First  is showing error 'cast' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection'

Comment: Which framework do you use? It's there since .NET 3.5. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @user1702346: Just use `GridView1.Rows(0)`, edited my answer accordingly.